# Swift Protocols: Adding Protocol conformance to an Instance

Tags: ios, swift, protocols, swift-protocols

I'm trying to understand how to add a protocol conformance to an instance if the instance has a particular value. This is a "stupid" example of what I'm trying to understand.

```
enum TypeOfFigure {
  case square, circle, triangle
}

protocol Figure {
    var type: TypeOfFigure { get }
}
protocol Square {}
protocol Circle {}
protocol Triangle {}


class FigureType: Figure {
    let type: TypeOfFigure

    init (type: TypeOfFigure) {
        self.type = type
        switch type {
        case .square: //extension self: Square {}
        case .circle: //extension self: Circle {}
        case .triangle: //extension self: Triangle {}
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I propose an alternative approach**

You can use a factory method:

```
class FigureTypeFactory {
    static func createFigure(withType type: TypeOfFigure) -> Figure {
        switch type {
            case .square: return new FigureSquare()
            case .circle: return new FigureCircle()
            case .triangle: return new FigureTriangle()
        }
    }
}

class Figure { }

class FigureSquare: Figure, Square { }
```

Comment: Much better approach IMO.

Comment: Thank you, this is my actual approach, but in this case I have to declare too many classes, I was looking for something more coincise.

Comment: @AndreaMiotto Can you update your post with the methods/properties of those protocols? This may help me to think other solutions

Comment: here: https://github.com/AndreaMiotto/AmusementParkGeneratorPart2/blob/master/AmusementParkPassGeneratorPart2/PersonModel.swift if you scroll down you fill find the 2 Factory classes. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As of "The Swift Programming Language":

> The protocol can then be adopted by a class, structure, or enumeration to provide an actual implementation of those requirements. Any type that satisfies the requirements of a protocol is said to conform to that protocol.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html

Thus you can't add protocol conformance to a specific instance.